# Multiple Image upload in array Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Good evening guys, I got a problem in my code. I'm doing a gallery form with separate fields.

I'm always end up with a "none" output because it does not get my input even though I entered something in the thumbnails[] field.

Anyone got an idea on how can I manage to fix it and how can it be done. Thank you very much.

Here is my code in html:

```
Main Image:
<input type="file" name="file1" required/> 
Thumbnails:
<input type="file" name="thumbnails[]"  />
<input type="file" name="thumbnails[]"  />
<input type="file" name="thumbnails[]"  />
```

In my Controller:

```
    $config = array(
    'upload_path' => "./uploads/workplace/",
    'allowed_types' => "jpg|png|jpeg",
    'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
    'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
    'max_height' => "0",
    'max_width' => "0"
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('file1'))
    {
      $config = array(
      'upload_path' => "./uploads/workplace/",
      'allowed_types' => "jpg|png|jpeg",
      'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
      'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
      'max_height' => "0",
      'max_width' => "0"
      );
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);            
      if($this->upload->do_upload('thumbnails[]'))  
      {
        echo "yea";
      } 
      else
      {
        echo "none";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $config = array(
'upload_path' => "./uploads/workplace/", 
'allowed_types' => "jpg|png|jpeg",
'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is                 2 MB(2048 Kb)
'max_height' => "0",
'max_width' => "0"
);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

 foreach ($_FILES as $key) {

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($key)) {
             echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }else
        {
             echo "<strong>Your Thumb image has been successfully Uploded..!!</strong><br><br>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
       $count = count($_FILES['filename']['size']);
       //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_FILES);
       foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
       for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++)
       {
       $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
       $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
       $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
       $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
       $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];
       $config['upload_path'] = './acontrol/document/';
       $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
       $this->load->library('upload', $config);
       $this->upload->initialize($config);
       $this->upload->do_upload();
       $data = $this->upload->data();
       //echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->upload->data());//die;
       $file_rename=str_replace(".","_",$data['file_name']);
       $names='acontrol/document/'.$data['file_name'];

       if($data['file_name']!=""){
            $data=array(
                'fol5_id'=>$this->input->post('fol5_id'),
                'doc_file'=>$names,
                'doc_size'=>$value['size'][$s],
                'delete_status'=>"NO"
            );
            //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);die;
            $this->model->insertData("dms_client_doc",$data);
          }
       }
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue